# Tikz large bullet

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to get some information on how to plot graphs from [this very interesting and nice open book](http://discrete.openmathbooks.org/dmoi3/sec_gt-intro.html) (Discrete Mathematics: An Open Introduction, Oscar Levin) and [its source code](https://github.com/oscarlevin/discrete-book/blob/master/ptx/bookinfo.ptx).

This is the code copied and pasted from the original (without configuration!):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (A) at (90+360/5:1);
    \coordinate (B) at (90+2*360/5:1);
    \coordinate (C) at (90+3*360/5:1);
    \coordinate (D) at (90+4*360/5:1);
    \coordinate (E) at (90:1);

    \draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- (E) -- (A);
    \foreach \x in {(A), (B), (C), (D), (E)}{
        \fill \x \v;
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And this what I get:

[image]

> There should be some initialization to get the vertices bigger as in the linked book:

[image]

> I would prefer a direct link to the lines of the linked source code (referring to the initialization file and to the file containing the copied lines), so that in the future I can refer directly there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not define `\v` but I suspect it may be a macro for a circle. Nevertheless, things can be simplified.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\tikzset{fancy ngon/.style={regular polygon,draw,minimum width=2cm,regular polygon sides=#1,alias=ngon,
append after command={foreach \XX in {1,...,#1} {(ngon.corner \XX) node[bullet]}}},
bullet/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=1.5pt,node contents={}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (A) at (90+360/5:1);
    \coordinate (B) at (90+2*360/5:1);
    \coordinate (C) at (90+3*360/5:1);
    \coordinate (D) at (90+4*360/5:1);
    \coordinate (E) at (90:1);

    \draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- (E) -- (A);
    \foreach \x in {(A), (B), (C), (D), (E)}{
        \fill \x circle[radius=2pt];
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[fancy ngon=5]{};
    \node[fancy ngon=6] at (3,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I thought that I destroyed the web page with my last click...

Comment: How do you move `[radius=2pt]` into `tikzset`? bullet is a standard style that is overriden? could I define instead `mybullet` and in the pic reference to it?

Comment: @PeptideChain Yes, or you could just use `bullet/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=2pt,node contents={}}` (where I replaced `1.5pt` by `2pt`).

Comment: thank you, I understand