# Tikz radius of the bullets with node

Tags: tikz-pgf

In the following picture the first graph has the correct bullet size, the second should have the same.

> I would like the second one to be changed in order to get the right size of the bullet **without having to specify the radius in the body but only in the style definition**. Why? Because I prefer the approach of the second graph.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (1) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (2) at (0,-1);
    \coordinate (3) at (-1,0);
    \coordinate (4) at (-1,-1);
    \coordinate (5) at (1,0);
    \coordinate (6) at (1,-1);

    \draw (1) to[out=40,in=140,looseness=4,loop] (1) ;
    \draw (1) to[out=150,in=30] (3) ;
    \draw (1) to[out=210,in=-30] (3) ;
    \draw (5) to[out=150,in=30] (1) ;
    \draw (5) to[out=210,in=-30] (1) ;

    \draw (3) -- (4) ;
    \draw (1) -- (2) ;
    \draw (5) -- (6) ;
    \draw (4) -- (2) ;
    \draw (2) -- (6) ;
    \foreach \x in {(1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6)}{
        \fill \x circle[radius=2pt];
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

\bigskip

\begin{tikzpicture}[bullet/.style={circle, fill, minimum size=2pt,
              inner sep=2pt, outer sep=0pt},nodes=bullet]
    \draw (18:1cm) node (2){} -- (90:1cm) node (3){} -- (162:1cm) node (4){} -- 
          (234:1cm) node (5){} -- (306:1cm) node (1){} -- (2);
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: `\draw (18:1cm) node (2){} -- (90:1cm) node (3){} -- (162:1cm) node (4){} -- 
          (234:1cm) node (5){} -- (306:1cm) node (1){} -- (2);`? That is, the size of the bullets is so large because the nodes have contents and fit these contents.

Comment: @marmot I would like this `[bullet/.style={circle, fill, minimum size=2pt,
              inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt},nodes=bullet]` to be changed, and not the part you posted in the comment.

Comment: @marmot I understand... hmm. And how I get a circle with 2pt radius and a label?

Comment: @marmot going from `\coordinate` to `node` change many aspects

Comment: As long as you give the nodes contents, these contents will show, You get a circle by either using a node or a pic. Yes, going from coordinate to node changes many aspects, and giving the nodes contents leads to additional changes.

Comment: @marmot Then I leave the label blank and I add a separate label, correct? I'm trying to get a somehow "standard" approach to avoid problems in the long run.

Comment: This is one way. You need to decide whether the node should have contents or not. In [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/497580/121799) the `bullet/.style` was defined with `contents={}` in order to make sure the nodes do not have contents.

Comment: @marmot Of course I remove the labels (from the node, but for sure I need a label). I have edited the question. The points are still not exactly of the same size, some fine tuning is needed .  The label should be another object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This adds labels and makes the bullets the same size as the circles.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (1) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (2) at (0,-1);
    \coordinate (3) at (-1,0);
    \coordinate (4) at (-1,-1);
    \coordinate (5) at (1,0);
    \coordinate (6) at (1,-1);

    \draw (1) to[out=40,in=140,looseness=4,loop] (1) ;
    \draw (1) to[out=150,in=30] (3) ;
    \draw (1) to[out=210,in=-30] (3) ;
    \draw (5) to[out=150,in=30] (1) ;
    \draw (5) to[out=210,in=-30] (1) ;

    \draw (3) -- (4) ;
    \draw (1) -- (2) ;
    \draw (5) -- (6) ;
    \draw (4) -- (2) ;
    \draw (2) -- (6) ;
    \foreach \x in {(1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6)}{
        \fill \x circle[radius=2pt];
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

\bigskip

\begin{tikzpicture}[bullet/.style={circle, fill,minimum size=4pt,
              inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt},nodes=bullet]
    \draw (18:1cm) node[label=18:A] (2){} 
    -- (90:1cm) node[label=90:B] (3){} -- (162:1cm) node[label=162:C] (4){} -- 
          (234:1cm) node[label=234:D] (5){} -- (306:1cm) node[label=306:E] (1){} -- (2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much. this is exactly what I need.

Comment: I have added a new Q, because the label on the edges are now bullets. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/497965

Answer (score 3):

For theoretical interests:

I think you are looking for:

```
bullet/.style={circle, fill,  
minimum size=4pt,
inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt},nodes=bullet
```

Compare:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,-2) node[minimum size=2cm,draw,circle] {2cm};

\draw (0,-2) node[minimum size=4cm,draw,circle] {};
\draw[red] (0,-2) circle(2cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Same size of the last two ones:

[image]

So

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm, tikz]{standalone}
%\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[bullet/.style={circle, fill,  
minimum size=4pt,
inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt},nodes=bullet]
    \coordinate (1) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (2) at (0,-1);
    \coordinate (3) at (-1,0);
    \coordinate (4) at (-1,-1);
    \coordinate (5) at (1,0);
    \coordinate (6) at (1,-1);

    \draw (1) to[out=40,in=140,looseness=4,loop] (1) ;
    \draw (1) to[out=150,in=30] (3) ;
    \draw (1) to[out=210,in=-30] (3) ;
    \draw (5) to[out=150,in=30] (1) ;
    \draw (5) to[out=210,in=-30] (1) ;

    \draw (3) -- (4) ;
    \draw (1) -- (2) ;
    \draw (5) -- (6) ;
    \draw (4) -- (2) ;
    \draw (2) -- (6) ;
    \foreach \x in {(1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6)}{
 \node[bullet, red, outer sep=0pt, xshift=4pt] at \x {};
\fill \x circle[radius=2pt];
%\node[bullet, red] at \x {};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

\bigskip

\begin{tikzpicture}[bullet/.style={circle, fill, minimum size=2pt,
              inner sep=2pt, outer sep=0pt},nodes=bullet]
    \draw (18:1cm) node (2){} -- (90:1cm) node (3){} -- (162:1cm) node (4){} -- 
          (234:1cm) node (5){} -- (306:1cm) node (1){} -- (2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,-2) node[minimum size=2cm,draw,circle] {2cm};

\draw (0,-2) node[minimum size=4cm,draw,circle] {};
\draw[red] (0,-2) circle(2cm);
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, what is `bullet/.style={circle, fill, draw=red, 
minimum size=4pt-\pgflinewidth,
inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt}` good for? You add a `draw` and then subtract the line width to maintain the overall size. For single-color nodes it is arguably easier not to add draw, and not to subtract anything. AFAIK the OP wanted single-color nodes.