# Tikz: After changing the node, the label on the edges are compromised

Tags: tikz-pgf

This is a follow up question to [Tikz radius of the bullets with node](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/497948/).

> Now that the style of all node has been changed, the labels of the edges are "compromised". What is a standard way to solve this problem?
>   Is it possible to define two aliases of node, say `nodeLb` and `nodePt`?

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[bullet/.style={circle, fill,minimum size=4pt,
              inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt},nodes=bullet]
    \draw (18:1cm) node[label=18:2] (2){} to[out=124,in=-16] node[above right] {c}
          (90:1cm) node[label=90:3] (3){} -- node[above right] {e}
          (162:1cm) node[label=162:4] (4){} to[out=-52,in=88] node[above right] {g}
          (234:1cm) node[label=234:5] (5){} -- node[above right] {h}
          (306:1cm) node[label=126:1] (1){} -- node[above right] {b} (2);
    \draw (2) to[out=164,in=-56] node[above right] {d} (3);
    \draw (4) to[out=-92,in=128] node[above right] {f} (5);
    \draw (1) to[out=0,in=-108,looseness=30,loop] node[above right] {a} (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you say `nodes=bullet`, which applies the style to all nodes. This is a convenient trick when all of the nodes should be bullet, but in this extended example this is no longer the case. So you may add bullet only to those nodes that should be a bullet. Also I recomment using `auto` or `auto,swap` instead of `above right` for the nodes along the edges.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[bullet/.style={circle, fill,minimum size=4pt,
              inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt}]
    \draw (18:1cm) node[bullet,label=18:2] (2){} to[out=124,in=-16] 
    node[auto,swap] {c}
          (90:1cm) node[bullet,label=90:3] (3){} -- node[auto,swap] {e}
          (162:1cm) node[bullet,label=162:4] (4){} to[out=-52,in=88] node[auto] {g}
          (234:1cm) node[bullet,label=234:5] (5){} -- node[auto,swap] {h}
          (306:1cm) node[bullet,label=126:1] (1){} -- node[auto,swap] {b} (2);
    \draw (2) to[out=164,in=-56] node[auto] {d} (3);
    \draw (4) to[out=-92,in=128] node[auto,swap] {f} (5);
    \draw (1) to[out=0,in=-108,looseness=30,loop] node[auto] {a} (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you, I should now have all the needed tools.

Comment: @PeptideChain You're welcome! Just from looking at the questions you wrote I am wondering if you are ultimately interested in the `graphdrawing` library. If you look e.g. at the example on the bottom of p. 416 of the pgfmanual v3.1.3, you see an example.

Comment: I looked quickly at the library, but I prefer to have full control of the graphics, and I like very much (aesthetically) the graph resulted from  your answers.